# IntelliJ command line error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command-line, cmd, terminal

In the configurations I have edited the workspace to a data folder where i have json and csv files that are going to be used in my program. My end goal is to have the user be able to type in the terminal:

java Main.java booking.json

assuming they are in the same folder as Main.java and have booking.json be stored as args[0]. However, the terminal is giving me

Error: Could not find or load main class Main

What can I do to fix this? I can try to run the command from somewhere else but will the configuration affect the terminal command and where the arguments are looked for?

Comment: You need to compile it first.

Comment: It's compiled. There is a Main.class

Comment: But your command says `Main.java`.

Comment: does not work with: java Main booking.json either (same error message)